# How can I get the contents of the "feedback" box from Google searches?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, google-search, google-search-api

When you ask a question or request the definition of a word in a Google search, Google gives you a summary of the answer in the *"feedback"* box.

For example, when you search for `define apple` you get this result:

[image: example of feedback]

Now, I would like to make it clear that **I do not** need the entire page or the other results, I just need this box:

[image: highlighted example of feedback]

How can I use the `Requests` and `Beautiful Soup` modules to get the contents of this *"feedback"* box in Python 3?

If that is not possible can I use the Google Search Api to get the contents of the *"feedback"* box?

I have found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32443610/how-get-intelligent-cards-answer-from-google-search) on SO but the OP has not specified the language, there are no answers and I fear that the two comments are outdated as this question was asked nearly 9 months ago.

Thank you for your time & help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is nice idea

program can be started with
python3 defineterm.py apple

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3.5
# defineterm.py

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import html
import codecs

searchterm = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])

url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=define+' + searchterm
res = requests.get(url)
try:
    res.raise_for_status()
except Exception as exc:
    print('error while loading page occured: ' + str(exc))

text = html.unescape(res.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
prettytext = soup.prettify()

#next lines are for analysis (saving raw page), you can comment them
frawpage = codecs.open('rawpage.txt', 'w', 'utf-8')
frawpage.write(prettytext)
frawpage.close()

firsttag = soup.find('h3', class_="r")
if firsttag != None:
    print(firsttag.getText())
    print()

#second tag may be changed, so check it if not returns correct result. That might be situation for all searched tags.
secondtag = soup.find('div', {'style': 'color:#666;padding:5px 0'})
if secondtag != None:
    print(secondtag.getText())
    print()

termtags = soup.findAll("li", {"style" : "list-style-type:decimal"})

count = 0
for tag in termtags:
    count += 1
    print( str(count)+'. ' + tag.getText())
    print()
```

make script as executable

then in ~/.bashrc
this line can be added

```
alias defterm="/data/Scrape/google/defineterm.py "
```

putting correct path to script your place

then executing

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

program can be started with:

```
defterm apple (or other term)
```

Comment: Thank you, so very much for the answer and also the `defterm` script. I'm testing it right now. I've used my daily voting limit but I'll be back in ~2 hours to give you the vote you deserve :D Also I would like to ask for permission to modify the `defterm` script and put it on Github, once again thank you.

Comment: no problem for python script and defterm modify and posting in github

Answer (score 2):

It is easily done using *requests* and *bs4*, you just need to pull the text from the *div* with the class *lr_dct_ent*

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

h = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36"}
r = requests.get("https://www.google.ie/search?q=define+apple", headers=h).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)

print("\n".join(soup.select_one("div.lr_dct_ent").text.split(";")))
```

The main text is in an ordered list, the noun is in the div with the *lr_dct_sf_h* class:

```
In [11]: r = requests.get("https://www.google.ie/search?q=define+apple", headers=h).text
In [12]: soup = BeautifulSoup(r,"lxml")    
In [13]: div = soup.select_one("div.lr_dct_ent")    
In [14]: n_v = div.select_one("div.lr_dct_sf_h").text   
In [15]: expl = [li.text for li in div.select("ol.lr_dct_sf_sens li")]    
In [16]: print(n_v)
noun

In [17]: print("\n".join(expl))
1. the round fruit of a tree of the rose family, which typically has thin green or red skin and crisp flesh.used in names of unrelated fruits or other plant growths that resemble apples in some way, e.g. custard apple, oak apple.
used in names of unrelated fruits or other plant growths that resemble apples in some way, e.g. custard apple, oak apple.
2. the tree bearing apples, with hard pale timber that is used in carpentry and to smoke food.
```

Comment: Thank you, so very much for the answer. I'm testing it now. I've used my daily voting limit but I'll be back in ~2 hours to give you the vote you deserve :D

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to grab CSS selectors of this text by using the [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.de/search?q=define apple', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

syllables = soup.select_one('.frCXef span').text
phonetic = soup.select_one('.g30o5d span span').text
noun = soup.select_one('.h3TRxf span').text
print(f'{syllables}\n{phonetic}\n{noun}')

# Output:
'''
ap·ple
ˈapəl
the round fruit of a tree of the rose family, which typically has thin red or green skin and crisp flesh. Many varieties have been developed as dessert or cooking fruit or for making cider.
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing using [Google Direct Answer Box API](https://serpapi.com/direct-answer-box-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial of 5,000 searches.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "define apple",
  "google_domain": "google.com",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

syllables = results['answer_box']['syllables']
phonetic = results['answer_box']['phonetic']
noun = results['answer_box']['definitions'][0] # array output
print(f'{syllables}\n{phonetic}\n{noun}')

# Output:
'''
ap·ple
ˈapəl
the round fruit of a tree of the rose family, which typically has thin red or green skin and crisp flesh. Many varieties have been developed as dessert or cooking fruit or for making cider.
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi