# Get source code containing all information in google feedback box?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to parse all the text in Google feedback cards using BeautifulSoup.

For query "*define apple*" Google shows info card with a
[drop down menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCbTZ.png). I want to parse all the text in [there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69QIH.png).

The similar questions is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37381946/how-can-i-get-the-contents-of-the-feedback-box-from-google-searches)
but the solution doesn't parses the full box (after drop down) because the source code fetch by `requests.get(url)` doesn't contain that information.

Is there a way that I can get the whole source code without **selenium**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do get all the source back using *requests*, the only issue you may have is some of the output are images:

```
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36",
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://www.google.ie/search?q=define+apple", headers=headers).content, "lxml")


div = soup.select("div.lr_dct_ent span")
desc = "\n".join(sp.text.strip("; ") for sp in div)
img = soup.select_one("div.lr_dct_ent").find_next("img")
print(desc)
print(img["src"])
print "\n".join(d.text for d in  soup.select("div.vk_sh.vk_gy"))
```

Which gives you:

```
apple
ˈap(ə)l/
ˈap(ə)l

noun
noun: apple
plural noun: apples
noun: apple tree
plural noun: apple trees
the round fruit of a tree of the rose family, which typically has thin green or red skin and crisp flesh.
used in names of unrelated fruits or other plant growths that resemble apples in some way, e.g. custard apple, oak apple.
the tree bearing apples, with hard pale timber that is used in carpentry and to smoke food.
Old English æppel, of Germanic origin; related to Dutch appel and German Apfel .
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
Origin
Use over time for: apple
```